# Is GObject the best way for creating menu options with signals in Clutter?

Tags: c, gnome, glib, gobject, clutter

I want to create a vertical menus with focus switching ability.

Do i need to do it using GObject way to create a custom option with its own event signal or should i create it separately without GObject ?

Any suggestion would help. And can anyone give me links for proper example codes where coding is done in production environment instead of fancy examples.

Comment: If you want proper example code, look at some of the Gnome desktop applications on git.gnome.org.

Answer (score 0):

You have clutter tag with your question so I assume you want to use clutter. In that case you could put your menu items as ClutterActor objects into ClutterGroup and handle menu navigation logic on the container level. This is trivial for keyboard events but for mouse navigation you can intercept them on each menu item and then pass it down to the container with item id or something. It is very simple with clutter. Unfortunately, I have no code samples to share at the moment.